# How to replace chmod command in windows?

Tags: android, windows, gradle

I ran a project in React Native and got an error: "Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up". I found a solution to run the command "chmod + x gradlew", but I am working with Windows so I had to use icacls. But even after I ran the "icacls gradlew.bat / grant Users: F" command, I got the same error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 99% chance it's not permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `chmod` command in windows it's linux command.

You can achieve by file permission properties or use use `cacls` or `attrib` commands in shell.

**Edit**

You can use `chmod` by installing [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/)

Comment: I tried it, but still have the same error.

Comment: I have edit the answer please check.